# update ruby -version fail on mac

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

Now I am trying to update my ruby version from 1.8(system default) to 1.9.3.

After I install ruby 1.9.3:

```
==> Downloading http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p362.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file missing/setproctitle.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362 --enable-shared --disable
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
NOTE: By default, gem installed binaries will be placed into:
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.
==> Summary
```

But When I change my ruby version, I got this:

```
macmatoMac-Pro:1.9.3-p362 mac$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default

ruby-1.9.3-p327 is not installed.

To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p327'
```

What should I do?  thanks :)

Comment: Don't try to update your Apple-installed version of Ruby. That is there for Apple's use. Instead, use RVM or rbenv to install a copy of Ruby in a sandbox for your use. Apple's installed version is used by Apple-installed applications, and messing with their version could cause problems down the line during updates, or cause their software to stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM knows nothing about the version of 1.9.3 in `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby`. You can't install a version of Ruby into an arbitrary location and expect RVM to inherit it or understand where it's located, because you installed it outside RVM's control. RVM is designed to manage its own sandboxed versions of Ruby using `rvm install some_ruby_version`.

You could change your path to point to the Ruby you installed, and use `rvm use system` to get RVM to step out of the way, but, at that point, you won't have any of the added features that make RVM nice to have, such as gem-set support.

Read through RVM's documentation to understand how it works, especially [how to install new versions of Ruby](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing/).

Comment: I think ruby 1.9.3 is already installed, but I can not change the version of ruby to 1.9.3 ):

Comment: As I said in the second paragraph, you can change to using 1.9.3, but you won't be able to manage it with RVM.

Comment: *WHERE* did you add it to the path? At the start or the end?